# Exception When Registering List Change Listener

Tags: java, exception, generics, user-interface, javafx

I just added this code to my list program and I got an exception from it. I'm not exactly sure what is happening, and it avoided my efforts to debug with it. Specifically, the exception happened on the assignment of the new list. rankList is a `ListView<Rank>`

```
 rankList.getItems().addListener(new ListChangeListener<Rank>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Rank> c) {

                 List<? extends Rank> ranks = c.getAddedSubList();
                 Collections.sort(ranks, (Rank t, Rank t1)
                 -> Long.compare(t.getNumericalRankApproximation(),
                 t1.getNumericalRankApproximation()));
                 setValue(ranks.get(ranks.size()).getNumericalRankApproximation());
                 increment();
            }
        });
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid Change state: next() must be called before inspecting the Change.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to iterate over the `change` that is passed to the `onChanged` method. See the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ListChangeListener.Change.html) for details, but something like

```
 rankList.getItems().addListener(new ListChangeListener<Rank>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Rank> c) {
                 while (c.next()) {
                     if (c.wasAdded()) {
                         List<? extends Rank> ranks = c.getAddedSubList();
                         Collections.sort(ranks, (Rank t, Rank t1)
                         -> Long.compare(t.getNumericalRankApproximation(),
                         t1.getNumericalRankApproximation()));
                         setValue(ranks.get(ranks.size()).getNumericalRankApproximation());
                         increment();
                     }
                 }
            }
        });
```

Comment: I got a stack overflow from this.

Comment: Not sure you have posted enough code to help with that. Presumably there is a recursive call somewhere. Can you identify where it is coming from, using the stack trace?

Comment: For some reason it just duplicates my ObservableList content, I wish I could get only the added items with getAddedSubList() or getList().